# How to fix DOSBox Caps Lock?

Tags: keyboard, emulator, dosbox

I installed DOSBox version 0.74 and found to be unable to type in lower case except if you hold only the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. The <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key seems non functioning within the emulator. I tried to re-assign the key using the less-than-key "<" by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> where the key mapping could be configured, but the emulator doesn't respond after saving the modifications. Please inform how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found I am unable to type in lower case except if I hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

It sounds like you may have the `Hold` option enabled. Assuming you have the [latest version of DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1), try the following:

- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to bring up the keyboard mapper.
- Select the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> (`CLCK`) key with your mouse (it should turn green).
- Next to the `mod1` option, it should say `hold`. This option should *not* have a white box next to it. If it does, click the white box so that it turns black.
- Using the mouse, click `Save` then click `Exit`.

*ex. DOSBox 0.74-3 Keyboard Mapper*

[image: DOSBox 0.74-3 Keyboard Mapper Settings - Screenshot]

---

*If this doesn't solve the issue, you may want to simply try deleting any `mapper-0.74-3.map` files under ex. `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\DOSBox` or perhaps even try reinstalling DOSBox*

---